# how to get node href in sql this example?

Tags: html, sql

how to get node href in sql this example?
this is my code:

```
    <h2 style="font-size: 2.3em; text-align:center;margin-bottom:10px;">SELECT YOUR ACER  SERIES</h2>
<div class="models_selector_block" >
  <div class="ls_black_series_selector "  style="min-width:500px;"><b>LAPTOPS</b>

    <DIV class="msb_item">
        <a class="ser_selector" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ASPIRE/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ASPIRE/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ASPIRE/">ASPIRE</a> 
         <br/>
        <a style="color:#000; font-size:10px;padding-left: 15px;" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ASPIRE/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ASPIRE/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ASPIRE/">ASPIRE LCD Screen</a>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="msb_item"> 
        <a class="ser_selector" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/EXTENSA/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/EXTENSA/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/EXTENSA/">EXTENSA</a>
        <br/>
        <a style="color:#000; font-size:10px;padding-left: 15px;" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/EXTENSA/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/EXTENSA/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/EXTENSA/">EXTENSA LCD Screen</a>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="msb_item"> 
        <a class="ser_selector" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/FERRARI/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/FERRARI/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/FERRARI/">FERRARI</a> 
        <br/>
        <a style="color:#000; font-size:10px;padding-left: 15px;" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/FERRARI/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/FERRARI/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/FERRARI/">FERRARI LCD Screen</a> 
    </DIV> 
    <DIV class="msb_item"> 
        <a class="ser_selector" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ICONIA/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ICONIA/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ICONIA/">ICONIA</a> 
        <br/>
        <a style="color:#000; font-size:10px;padding-left: 15px;" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ICONIA/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ICONIA/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ICONIA/">ICONIA LCD Screen</a> 
    </DIV> 
    <DIV class="msb_item"> 
        <a class="ser_selector" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/TRAVELMATE/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/TRAVELMATE/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/TRAVELMATE/">TRAVELMATE</a> 
        <br/>
        <a style="color:#000; font-size:10px;padding-left: 15px;" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/TRAVELMATE/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/TRAVELMATE/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/TRAVELMATE/">TRAVELMATE LCD Screen</a> 
    </DIV> 
    <DIV class="msb_item"> 
        <a class="ser_selector" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/Other Acer Models/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/Other Acer Models/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/Other Acer Models/">Other Acer Models</a> 
        <br/>
        <a style="color:#000; font-size:10px;padding-left: 15px;" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/Other Acer Models/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/Other Acer Models/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/Other Acer Models/">Other Acer Models LCD Screen</a> 
    </DIV> 
  </div>
  <div class="ls_black_series_selector  phone_tablet_block" >
    <b>TABLETS</b>
    <DIV class="msb_item"> 
        <a class="ser_selector" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ASPIRE/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ASPIRE/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ASPIRE/">ASPIRE</a> 
        <br/>
        <a style="color:#000; font-size:10px;padding-left: 15px;" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ASPIRE/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ASPIRE/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ASPIRE/">ASPIRE LCD Screen</a> 
    </DIV> 
    <DIV class="msb_item"> 
        <a class="ser_selector" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ICONIA/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ICONIA/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ICONIA/">ICONIA</a> 
        <br/>
        <a style="color:#000; font-size:10px;padding-left: 15px;" href="javascript:if(confirm(%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ICONIA/  \n\nThis file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon.  \n\nDo you want to open it from the server?%27))window.location=%27http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ICONIA/%27" tppabs="http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/series/Acer/ICONIA/">ICONIA LCD Screen</a> 
    </DIV> 
   </div><br clear="both"/>
  </div>
          '



   SELECT  t.v.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as [Name Of Brand],
                  t.v.value('@href','nvarchar(max)') as [URL Local]       
          FROM  @htmlXML.nodes('div/a') as t(v)

or 
      SELECT  t.v.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as [Name Of Brand],
          t.v.value('@title','nvarchar(max)') as [Title Of Brand],
          t.v.value('@href','nvarchar(max)') as [URL Local],
          t.v.value('@tppabs','nvarchar(max)') as [URL Site]
  FROM  @htmlXML.nodes('div/div[1]/DIV/a[1]') as t(v)
```

i want to dynamic nodes 
div/div[i]/DIV/a[i]
i am try with codes but i can not your solve my problem.
very important for me.
thanks,thanks

Thanks for your tips........................................................................................................................................

Comment: Your xml is not valid `<br> .. <DIV class=msb_item>  .. <br/>   .. </DIV>` I don't believe it can be parsed at all.

Comment: <DIV class=msb_item>   to  <DIV class="msb_item">  with c# and  delete <br> with c#

Comment: Now with correct XML, isn't your second query getting what you need ?

Comment: i can getting with query but i want to dynamic query for getting div[1] to div[10]

Comment: I see 3 level of `div`. If you mean you need rows for every `div` at the deepest level, remove [1] form intermidiate `div` in path: `FROM  @htmlXML.nodes('div/div/DIV/a[1]') as t(v)`